# Wait until function is finished

Tags: javascript

What is a best way to execute function until before call is finished?

Example JavaScript function:

```
var notifyState = function(state) {
setTimeout(function () {
  /*Do something*/
}, 2000);
};
```

Then I call function twice:

```
notifyState('State1');
notifyState('State2');
```

This functions executing in paraller. What best way to execute them sequentially? I can only modify `notifyState` function. `notifyState` can execute only with one parameter.

**Update:**
Function `notifyState` informs what actual state is in flash game. It saves it in html code, when state change then state is override. In selenium test I downloading state from html code, but state change too fast that selenium not noticed this, so I tried sleep JavaScript.

Comment: time for `Callback`

Comment: First of all... there's no multithreading in javascript so your function will always be run sequentially but you can't tell in which order

Comment: @PraveenJeganathan: Callback isn't going to work if OP can only modify `notifyState` function

Comment: Are you able to change the calls to the function?

Comment: @musefan you're right, I failed to note it.

Comment: @SOReader: I know javascript run only in one thread, but both function executing at the same time.

Comment: @oGeez - Yes, I can create helper function to call notifyState

Comment: @SOReader: there is multithreading in JavaScript, see web workers: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Performance/Using_web_workers

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It depends on whether you want *#notifyState* to use setTimeout or not. If you don't need the *setTimeout* then you just re-write as follows:

```
var notifyState = function(state) {
  /* Do something */
}

notifyState('State 1');
notifyState('State 2');
```

If you want to keep the *setTimeout* and chain the calls, so that the second notify is executed after the first, you will have to provide a callback:

```
var notifyState = function(state, callback) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    /* Do something */
    if (callback) {
      callback();
    }
  }, 2000);
}

notifyState('State 1', function() {
  notifyState('State 2');
});
```

**EDIT**

Seems that the OP problem is different. My understanding is that your are providing *#notifyState* function as a callback to a 3rd party Flash that you don't control and you want to ensure that calls to notifyState execute in the same order and one after another, so you don't have 2 parallels calls to *notifyState* running at the same time. To achieve this you will need to introduce a queue that will keep the states and change the *notifyState* function in a way to execute only one state at the time. I will assume your need for the *setTimeout* is important here and keep it that way. See the code below:

```
var Queue = [],
    running = false;
var notifyState = function(state) {
  if (running) {
    Queue.push(state);
  } else {
    running = true;
    setTimeout(function() {
      /* Do something */
      running = false;
      var nextState = Queue.pop();
      if (nextState) {
        notifyState(nextState);
      }
    }, 2000);
  }
}
```

Comment: I can execute `notifyState` only with one parameter (actual state). I don't know what state will be next.

Answer (score 2):

Add an optional parameter that will act as a callback function. Check that the parameter is in fact a function, if it is, run it.

```
var notifyState = function(state,fn) {
    setTimeout(function () {
      /*DoSomething*/
      if(typeof(fn)=='function'){ fn(); }
    }, 2000);
};
```

You can then call the functions like so:

```
notifyState('State1', function(){
    notifyState('State2');
});
```

[<kbd>JSFiddle</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/oGeez/f8NS6/)

Comment: but Op mentioned `can only modify notifyState function.` So I think OP can't use it

Comment: So the OP can modify the function itself but not the call to the function?

Comment: based on the question it seems like that, only OP can clarify it.

Comment: I may have misunderstood, thanks for noting - I will wait for clarification.

Comment: It's work but not for me. I get from Flash application external call only with one parameter (actual state). I don't know which state will be next. Maybe use something like locker?

Comment: @estradowiec can you elaborate more what you want to achieve ?

It seems that you are writing the notifyState function, but it gets called by the Flash and provided only one parameter. In case you want to ensure that your calls to notifyState will execute sequentially you will need to use a queue.

Why you use the #setTimeout in your case ?

Comment: @edzhelyov - function `notifyState` informs what actual state is in flash game. It saves it in html code, when state change then state is override. In selenium test I downloading state from html code, but state change too fast that selenium not noticed this, so I tried sleep javascript.

Comment: @estradowiec if you want to implement *sleep* in javascript you can't achieve that with *setTimeout*. You will need to do something like:

    while cycle and check that 2 seconds have elapsed after you first enter the while cycle.

Comment: @estradowiec if you are concerned with your tests I would suggest that you keep the states in array or change your notifyState function for the tests only. So instead of trying to obtain the state from the HTML you can inspect an Array with all the state changes, this way you will be able to see how the state changes over-time without affecting your javascript code, in a way that you will do that if you *sleep*. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
var notifyState = function(state, callback) {
    setTimeout(function () {

    /*Do something*/

    callback();

    }, 2000);
};
```

Calling function:

```
var state1CompleteHandler = function() {
    // code to execute when state 1 logic completes
    notifyState('State2');
}
notifyState('State1', state1CompleteHandler);
```